# Laravel BaseController vs \BaseController

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

The default HomeController class is defined using

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
```

However, when a resource controller is created via `artisan`, the class extends `\BaseController` instead of `BaseController`. Why is this, and what is the difference?

```
class TestResourceController extends \BaseController {
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference (in a default installation).  The `\` simply tells PHP to use the root [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) instead of any other class with the same name but on a different namespace.  If you were to create your own class called BaseController, PHP would not know which class to use unless it were explicity defined by the namespace, i.e. `MyNamespace\BaseController`.